# Summing Two Pandas Series Except the Total Only Shows only One Column Summed

Tags: pandas, dataframe

As a way of example, I am trying to sum two columns on every row, so as I filter down, I can pull a total for a number of different views.

Something simple like this:

```
df['Total'] = df['Series 1'] + df['Series 2']
```

However, when I check the sum of this new colum `'Total'` the total matches what I would get when I simiply sum the `df['Series 1']` column.

Now if I simply do something like `df['Series 1'].sum() + df['Series 1'].sum()`

The resulting sum results in the output I was expecting if I would have simply totaled the `df['Total']`

I can't think why this would be. Why is that summing each Series individually results in the total together, but simply adding the two columns together, is only pulling `Series 1` over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe the associative property. It is only true when there is no `NaN` values in the calculation. NaN values will throw the associative property off. Here the sample

```
sample df:
   Series 1  Series 2
0       1.0         0
1       7.0         0
2       NaN         9

df['Series 1'].sum()
Out[528]: 8.0

df['Series 2'].sum()
Out[530]: 9

df['Series 1'].sum() + df['Series 2'].sum()
Out[531]: 17.0

(df['Series 1'] + df['Series 2']).sum()
Out[531]: 8.0
```

As above example, the associative property doesn't hold true anymore.

Without your data, I just guess there are some `NaN` values in your `Series 1` and `Series 2`

Comment: You're right, once I run a .fillna() it sums to the expected amount.